# Filter one Dataframe on occurences in second Dataframe. Pyspark. Elegant solution needed

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm stuck with one problem. We have two input dataframes - upper_in and lower_in, and we need to filter row of upper_in DF on occurences in lower_in DF.
Thats means if line from upper_in is in lower_in the row will be written in the new DF (uppper_out).
If line from upper_in is not in lower_in, than it will be written to the othe DF (lower_out)

My straight-forward solution:

- Iterate through upper_in DF <--- Problem Here
- Check if content form upper_is in lower_in
- True - write to upper_out
- False - write to lower_out

```
upper_columns = upper_input.collect()
lower_columns = lower_input.collect()

# investigate map method

upper_output = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD(), upper_input.schema)
lower_output = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD(), lower_input.schema)

for upper_row, lower_row in zip(upper_columns, lower_columns):
#check if content is the same in upper and lower row
    if upper_row[selected_columns[0][0]] == lower_row[selected_columns[0][1]]:
         row_to_append = spark.createDataFrame([upper_row], upper_input.schema)
         upper_output = upper_output.union(row_to_append)
         row_to_append.unpersist()
     else:
         row_to_append = spark.createDataFrame([upper_row], lower_input.schema)
         lower_output = lower_output.union(row_to_append)
         row_to_append.unpersist()
```

But I'm looking for smth more elegant and without using .collect() function.

Theoretically .map() or .foreach() can be used, but than we need to
create smth like .pop() function for DF.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why don't you just use join?

Comment: @blackbishop Sound like good idea, but if I will use join (inner obviously), where will be stored rows that are not similar? resp. not in lower_in

Comment: But there are other types of join not only inner (left, semi,..).  You can also use [`exceptAll`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.exceptAll) here.

Comment: Dont you think that join wil be slow in case of millions of rows? Second, what type of join for this case is the best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`intersectAll`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.intersectAll) and [`exceptAll`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.exceptAll) to check the occurrences of the rows of `upper_in` in `lower_in`:

```
upper_out = upper_in.intersectAll(lower_in)
lower_out = upper_in.exceptAll(lower_in)
```

Alternatively, you can do a [`left_semi`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-join.html#semi-join) or [`left_anti`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-join.html#anti-join) join on all columns:

```
upper_out = upper_in.join(lower_in, upper_in.columns, 'left_semi')
lower_out = upper_in.join(lower_in, upper_in.columns, 'left_anti')
```

If you want to specify a list of columns to check, you can do:

```
cols = ['Location']
upper_out = upper_in.join(lower_in, cols 'left_semi')
lower_out = upper_in.join(lower_in, cols, 'left_anti')
```

Comment: God Solution, Thank you. But what if I want to specify columns that are needed to filtered by. example: column "Location" is in upper_in and lower_in, we need to filter similar, write whole row to upper_out, else to lower_out. Not as usefull in case of one cloumn, but point is to have multiple column selection to be filtered by